# Detecting C# and SQL Server memory conflicts

Tags: c#, sql-server, memory-management

I have a memory-intensive C# app that resides on the same server as SQL Server.

I have tweaks in my application to limit in-memory caching and I am aware of how to set (and have set) maximum memory limits on my SQL Server.

PROBLEM: When the C# app wants to use more memory than is available due to SQL Server's caching, my app slows greatly, presumably to venturing into Virtual Memory space. I can prevent this most of the time by eyeballing how much RAM is available and setting the appropriate values in my custom C# code (whether to cache to RAM and/or to SQL Server) and in SQL Server's settings.

HOWEVER: Sometimes the machine's memory usage goes beyond my eyeballed boundaries due to other processes on the machine, typical OS needs fluctuating, etc.

I have noticed that SQL Server will often yield RAM to other processes, such as Chrome, MS Word...  it doesn't seem to do so for my process.  I have a gut feeling that my C# app isn't actively using all of the cached data in SQL Server...

So, how do I detect when SQL Server won't yield the RAM to my application and/or how do I detect when my application cannot allocate additional bytes of physical RAM?

Comment: A guess like "presumably to venturing into Virtual Memory space" is not good enough.  Analyze more until you've got proof.

Comment: This is part of my question - how?  The Process.***64 values indicate existing VM usage, but how do I know when my process can't allocate additional RAM?

Comment: If a .NET process runs out of RAM, it will run a garbage collector, and try again.  You can monitor the number of garbage collections with performance monitor.  To detect swapping, look at "Pages Input / sec" in the "Memory" section.

Comment: @Andomar It's not only not good enough, it's completely nonsensical / betrays a lack of understanding of how memory management works. Absolutely every program will store everything in virtual memory under a protected-mode OS.

Comment: Keep 'em coming - every hint helps.  TY.  :)

Comment: Try this blog's -> [Server Memory Server Configuration Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx)  [Set a Fixed Amount of Memory (SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191144%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)